# Calculus 3 Max Dimension Problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Could someone explain how I would solve the following question? I am not sure where to begin:

A rectangular box with dimensions x,y and z is positioned in the first octant with one corner at the origin and three of its faces against the coordinate planes. The corner opposite to the origin must touch the plane ax + by + cz = d. Find the dimensions of the box with the largest possible volume that satisfies these conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the coordinate of the corner opposite to the origin be $(x,y,z)$.

The volume of the cuboid is then given by $xyz$; and $x,y,z$ must atisfy $ax+by+cz=d$. i.e. we have a constrained extremum problem.

Using Lagrange multipliers, we consider the function

$$F(x,y,z,\lambda) = xyz-\lambda(ax+by+cz-d)$$

and find the extremums of $F$. The setting the gradient of $F$ to $0$, we find that

\begin{align}
yz-\lambda a & = 0 \\
xz - \lambda b & = 0 \\
xy - \lambda c & = 0 \\
ax+by+cz & =d
\end{align}

Solving, we obtain

$$x = \frac{d}{3a} \qquad y = \frac{d}{3b} \qquad z = \frac{d}{3c} \qquad \lambda = \frac{d^2}{9abc}$$

and the extremized area is

$$xyz = \frac{d^3}{27abc}$$